# Less than or equal summations

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, proof-verification, real-numbers

[image: Prove this unequal]

Hi,I want to prove above unequal that consist of two summation both of this sides.It a formula in Computer Network to control Congestion.The way to prove it is not important, but because I weak in mathematical i want to know all thing about details. More information  about Network congestion! is available on below image(Raj Jain Proposal). In fact, finally I want to prove that the numerator is less or equal than denominator. I persist again that I want to know completely detail about the proof steps.

[Raj Jain Proposal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQAuB.jpg)

Comment: use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality

Comment: Thanks for res ponce.As I said I'm weak on mathematical. Can you get me more details about proof steps?

Answer (score 0):

From [RMS-AM inequality](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality),
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n}}\geq \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$$
where $x_i>0 \,\,\,\,\, \forall\,\,\,\,\,i\in \{1,2,\cdots n\}$.
Square both sides of inequality and you obtain what is stated in OP.

Comment: I need more help!

Comment: What you did not understand?

Comment: Actually it's not my response.At first i want to proof above unequatin.How you proved that left side equation is bigger or equal than right side?The answer of this question is my main response.

Comment: You can see the proof on the page I linked.

Comment: Can i do chat with you from gmail or yahoo??

Comment: Sorry, but that is not possible.

Comment: Is it possible introduce to me another related document that have proved my problem?

Comment: In my opinion, Art of Problem Solving provides the simplest proof for the inequality.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant understand. I think it's too abstract. Maybe various  document will help me better.